# Xamarin.Forms 4.0 CollectionView Pull-To-Refresh

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying out the pre-release CollectionView control for Xamarin.Forms 4.0 and I've run into a small hickup.
I've ben able to get binding, styling, etc. working perfectly, but I'm unable to figure out how to implement Pull-To-Refresh. This is in the shared code project and final product targets iOS and Android only.

I've been over Microsoft's documentation and haven't been able to find a clear solution for this. 
The only reference I've seen to anything remotely related to this issue comes from a GitHub discussion on the XF page ([Xamarin.Forms.CollectionView Spec Discussion](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3172)) where they mention that the `IsPUllToRefreshEnabled` functionality has been moved from the `ListView` API to a new `RefreshView` control.

Can anyone shine any light on this issue and if this is even possible to implement? (Data for collection view is fed by Refit API call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RefreshView is still in spec, not yet implemented [(see the Github page)](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5882)

However, from the comments, you can try and use [PullToRefresh Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh/), that allows pull to refresh on a scrollview or a listview.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I've gone with a good old-fashioned ListView until RefreshView is implemented.

Comment: Yeah, I've took the same approach until the collections are fully stable

Comment: Just to keep people updated, seems that Pull-To-Refresh for CollectionView has been released in the Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0 milestone (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5882)